# Different color vim vs less in tmux

Tags: vim, tmux, less, suckless-terminal

[image]

Both vim and less run inside tmux but they appear to have different `white` color, I really want to have less's white color in vim.

In tmux I have terminal settings (st terminal):

```
set -g default-terminal xterm-256color
set -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I want text in vim has same white color as in less (both in tmux). @jsotola

Comment: that is not a question ... it is a description of the desired result ... an example of a question is "where do i find the configuration files for abcd?